# What does __init__ method of Python immutable class, e.g. float look like?

Tags: python

It seems the `__init__` method of Python immutable class is meaningless, as after the creation of an object, attribute assignment is not allowed. But obviously the `__init__` method does exist for immutable object. How is it implemented? Does it have empty method body?

Comment: Often if you want to cache instances you'll use `__new__` to return a previously constructed object.  A common pattern we use is inheriting a tuple (immutable) through namedtuple and setting `__slots__ = ()` to prevent assignment to arbitrary attributes.

Comment: Are you looking for an *immutable* or *builtin* pattern?  From what I can tell, the builtin for a new float [is only defined in C](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/floatobject.c#l1788).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` does nothing and is simply inherited from `object`. All the work is done in `__new__`.

```
In [1]: float.__init__
Out[1]: <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects>

In [2]: float.__new__
Out[2]: <function float.__new__>
```

The definition of the `float` class's `tp_new` is `float_new`, which can be seen [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d2b8354e87f5/Objects/floatobject.c#l1802).